# NSTextView with custom space width

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I need to implement custom space separator with custom width between two part of paragraph in text view:

> AAAA AA A -------- BBB BBBBB B

This is separator must be included as non-editable character. So user can't delete it or modify.
I understand, that i must overload standard behavior of textview in some points (for example, when user press "delete" right after separator nothing will be deleted)

I have several ideas how accomplish this task:

1. Use elastic glyph attribute (there are mentions in documentation about it). But I can't find any documentation about how to use it.
2. Use tab symbol and NSTextTab for each paragraph, and in any modification to the paragraph recalculate position of tab.

I will be very grateful for any right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and wound up inserting blank images of the desired width into the textview.  The code for implementing this is here:
[Changing the width of the space character in NSTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248030)

Comment: I have posted a more straightforward solution under that question too.